# Running a Django server in a VMWare Virtual Machine

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, python, vmware

I am trying to run a Django instance in a VM (and also inside a virtual environment inside that VM, which may be the source of the problem).

I'm running Ubuntu 16.x, and I've got Django 1.10 installed with Python3.

However whenever I try to use the runserver command, the following happens:

If I try to run it without any arguments, I get this:

```
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

However if I try to assign it to any specific IP address, I get, `That IP address can't be assigned to.`

I just want to be able to go into my browser outside of the VM and access the site.

My network settings in VMWare are as follows:

```
Network connection:

Bridged: Connected directly to the physical network

Replicate physical network connection state checked
```

What am I doing incorrectly here?

Is running it from a virtual environment incorrect? Is there something I may have configured incorrectly with VMWare?

The computer I am trying to access the server from is a Windows 10 machine, but I don't think that's relevant, just including it for detail. The VM is local to this computer as well.